# Aligning Nested Divs and H2

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display the date before an h2 title.
The date is displayed as two boxes, one above the other.
The top box contains the day of the month, the bottom box the month and year.

the HTML (with test CSS) is as follows:-

```
  <div style="text-align: center;display: inline">
      <div style="border-radius:5px;font-size:20px;color:black;background-color:yellow;width:45px;height:30px">
          12
     </div>         
     <div style="border-radius:3px;font-size:10px;color:#fff;background-color:black;width:45px;height:15px">
          Dec-16
     </div>         
  </div>
```

This displays nicely at the beginning of the line.
But 
  This is H2 text
does not display on the sane line but the next one.

Because my "date container" is made of nested divs, this does not appear to align correctly.

This works fine aligned on the same line

```
  <div style="display:inline">This is DIV text</div>  
  <h2 style="display:inline">This is H2 text</h2>
```

This does not align correctly (as I wish)

```
  <div style="text-align: center;display: inline">
      <div style="border-radius:5px;font-size:20px;color:black;background-color:yellow;width:45px;height:30px">
          12
     </div>         
     <div style="border-radius:3px;font-size:10px;color:#fff;background-color:black;width:45px;height:15px">
          Dec-16
     </div>         
  </div>  
  <h2 style="display:inline">This is H2 text</h2>
```

TIA

Ephraim

Answer (score 2):

```html
<body style="display:table">
    <div style="text-align: center;display: table-cell">
      <div style="border-radius:5px;font-size:20px;color:black;background-color:yellow;width:45px;height:30px">
        12
      </div>         
      <div style="border-radius:3px;font-size:10px;color:#fff;background-color:black;width:45px;height:15px">
        Dec-16
      </div>         
  </div>  
  <h2 style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; padding-left: 10px;">This is H2 text</h2>  
</body>
```

Add
display: table for body 
display:table-cell for div and h2
vertical-align:middle for h2
It works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

Hope below snippet works for you.

```html
<div style="text-align: center; float: left">
  <div style="border-radius:5px;font-size:20px;color:black;background-color:yellow;width:45px;height:30px">
    12
  </div>         
  <div style="border-radius:3px;font-size:10px;color:#fff;background-color:black;width:45px;height:15px">
    Dec-16
  </div>         
</div>  
<h2 style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">This is H2 text</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

```html
<div style="text-align: center;display: inline-block">
      <div style="border-radius:5px;font-size:20px;color:black;background-color:yellow;width:45px;height:30px">
          12
     </div>         
     <div style="border-radius:3px;font-size:10px;color:#fff;background-color:black;width:45px;height:15px">
          Dec-16
     </div>         
  </div>  
  <h2 style="display:inline-block">This is H2 text</h2>
```